# Where to write some of Android Codings in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I have designed cordova web application which works in Android. But I am not getting code for thermal printer code.

I have developed this Thermal printer code in Android and same I want to add in Cordova.

How can I write Android coding in Cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement **Java** functionality in your Cordova app, you must use **plugins**. In this case you'll have to write your own. These links will get you started in the right direction:

[Plugin Development Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/)

[Sample Hello World Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-hello)

Start with the sample plugin first, once you understand its structure you should simply edit it to suit your needs, but make sure you constantly test it to ensure it still works.